# locally hosted cross browser screenshot tool

Tags: selenium, cross-browser-testing, open-source

I am browsing through the web in search of a tool that automatically lets me create screenshots of a given url for a range of different browsers and platforms.

I know that there is a wide range of online services, but I am looking for a solution that I can install on my own server because of security reasons.

Best case scenario:
I open a simple html page on my server on which I select a range of browsers and apply a URL. Then the server boots up different VMs, one for each browser. Then the server makes full page screenshots, bundles them somehow and presents them to me/the user in some way.

I have looked into selenium but as far as I have understood it will only be able to handle Browsers that are installed on my OS, correct?

The one system I have seen so far that grants what I am looking for is Browsershots, but their code (and documentation) is quite outdated. Which brings me here to this question: Are there any good open source projects out there which can deliver what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have looked into selenium but as far as I have understood it will only be able to handle Browsers that are installed on my OS, correct?

Yes

But there is [BrowseEmAll](https://www.browseemall.com/). It is commercial but does what you need: *On-Premises, Fast & Secure Cross Browser Testing. Live Testing, Screenshots and Code Analytics On Your Local Machine.*

It works by installing its own virtual box images with all the browsers and it manages them for you behind the scene.

Comment: I have seen BrowseEmAll in my own web research, but thought that they would still pass my local URLs through a tunnel to their own servers. But thanks, man! I will look into it tomorrow and give feedback if this is the thing I am looking for!

Comment: Ok, I have checked it and you are right. This does everything I need. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I never come up with a open source tool to do your task.so the only way is install all the browsers to your OS and test against them via selenium.
Other than that of you use some cloud hosted tool ot might not give the exact output that you are looking for.
So the best way is to use live browsers installed on your PC.

Comment: See answer of @Bobby231 :)